# MUI X Data Grid- how to make datagrid responsive

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

Datagrid is not responsive when I tried pagination

```
      <DataGrid
        getRowId={row => row.code}
        rows={allProducts}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={pageSize}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 12]}
        onPageSizeChange={newPageSize => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
        checkboxSelection
        onSelectionModelChange={handleCheckboxClick}
        autoHeight
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
        sx={{
          '& .hideRightSeparator > .MuiDataGrid-columnSeparator': {
            display: 'none'
          },
          'MuiDataGrid-columnHeader': { variant: 'body1' }
        }}
      />
```

rowsPerPageOptions is not visible when screen size is reduced
rowsperpage-invisible-on-page-shrink
[image]